# Find a List of Tags Based on Text Value of Children in Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I have a question about selecting a list of tags (or single tags) using a condition on one of the attributes of it's children. Specifically, given the HTML code:

```
<tbody>
<tr class="" data-row="0">
<tr class="" data-row="1">
<tr class="" data-row="2">
    <td align="right" csk="13">13</td>
    <td align="left" csk="Jones,Andre"><a href="/players/andre-jones-2.html">Andre Jones</a>       
    </td>
<tr class="" data-row="3">
    <td align="right" csk="7">7</td>
    <td align="left" csk="Jones,DeAndre"><a href="/players/deandre-jones-1.html">DeAndre Jones</a>
    </td>
 <tr class="" data-row="4">
 <tr class="" data-row="5">
```

I have a unicode variable coming from an external loop and I am trying to look through each row in the table to extract the `<tr>` tags with `Player==Table.tr.a.text` and to identify duplicate player names in `Table`. So, for instance, if there is more than one player with `Player=Andre Jones` the `MyRow` object returns all `<tr>` tags that contain that players name, while if there is only one row with `Player=Andre Jones`, then `MyRow` just contains the single element `<tr>` with anchor text attribute equal to `Andre Jones`. I've been trying things like

```
Table = soup.find('tbody')
MyRow = Table.find_all(lambda X: X.name=='tr' and Player == X.text)
```

But this returns `[]` for `MyRow`. If I use

```
MyRow = Table.find_all(lambda X: X.name=='tr' and Player in X.text)
```

This will pick any `<tr>` that has `Player` as a substring of `X.text`. In the example code above, it extracts both `<tr>` tags withe `Table.tr.td.a.text=='Andre Jones'` and `Table.tr.td.a.text=='DeAndre Jones'`. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this easily with XPath and lxml:

```
import lxml.html

root = lxml.html.fromstring('''...''')
td = root.xpath('//tr[.//a[text() = "FooName"]]')
```

The BeautifulSoup "equivalent" would be something like:

```
rows = soup.find('tbody').find_all('tr')
td = next(row for row in rows if row.find('a', text='FooName'))
```

Or if you think about it backwards:

```
td = soup.find('a', text='FooName').find_parent('tr')
```

Comment: The beautiful soup code you provided will only give me the first occurrence where `text='FooName'`. I've refined my question to be more specific about what I'm looking for.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever you desire. :)

***Solution1***

Logic: find the first tag whose tag name is tr and contains 'FooName' in this tag's text including its children.

```
# Exact Match  (text is unicode, turn into str)
print Table.find(lambda tag: tag.name=='tr' and 'FooName' == tag.text.encode('utf-8'))
# Fuzzy Match
# print Table.find(lambda tag: tag.name=='tr' and 'FooName' in tag.text)
```

Output:

```
<tr class="" data-row="2">
<td align="right" csk="3">3</td>
<td align="left" csk="Wentz,Parker">
<a href="/players/Foo-Name-1.html">FooName</a>
</td>
</tr>
```

***Solution2***

Logic: find the element whose text contains `FooName`, the `anchor` tag in this case. Then go up the tree and search for the all its parents(including ancestors) whose tag name is `tr`

```
# Exact Match
print Table.find(text='FooName').find_parent('tr')
# Fuzzy Match
# import re
# print Table.find(text=re.compile('FooName')).find_parent('tr')
```

Output

```
<tr class="" data-row="2">
<td align="right" csk="3">3</td>
<td align="left" csk="Wentz,Parker">
<a href="/players/Foo-Name-1.html">FooName</a>
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: @MarkClements Please mark the answer that helps you the most as accepted so it will be easy for other people to search.

Comment: The code seems to be matching either first or last names, rather than the entire name. So not only does it treat "Andre Jones" and "DeAndre Jones" as the same but also "Terrance" and "Terrance Saulsberry".

Comment: I'm running into an issue using either Solution 1 or Solution 2. I have two names `"Andre Jones"` and `"DeAndre Jones"` in the text attribute of `<a>` in two different rows. However, the code only picks out the `<tr>` tag with "DeAndre Jones". I can see this because if I use find_all in Solution 1 and `Player="Andre Jones"`, it returns a list with two elements: the `<tr>` tags with text `"Andre Jones"` and `"DeAndre Jones"`. However, if `Player="DeAndre Jones"` the code returns a list with a single element: the `<tr>` tag with text `"DeAndre Jones"`. I can't figure out what's going on here.

Comment: @MarkClements I commented out the old logic and put the exactly match solution there. I was using `fuzzy match` which was trying to find tags which contains fooname, that is why it returned multiple records for you. You need to customize the function that I have written to meet your flavor if you have further name matching problem, like using regular expression method that I have commented out.

Comment: What if I want to find every `<tr>` tag that has the same `FooName`? I want to implement a check for identical names so that, if there are no identical names, the list object generated from `find_all` has one `<tr>` element in it and if there are `N` identical names, the list object has `N` `<tr>` elements in it.  Your code with the `find` function will just find the first occurrence and when I use `find_all` with your exact matching specification, Solution 1 produce an empty list `[]` for all values of `Player`, which, e.g., is a string var of the form `u'Andre Jones'`. Thanks for the help.

Comment: To be more specific, I'm trying to pass a unicode variable `Player` to the `lambda` function.  Like this

`PlayerRow = Table.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name=='tr' and Player == tag.text.encode('utf-8'))`

However since `Player` is already unicode, I previously tried this

`PlayerRow = Table.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name=='tr' and Player == tag.text)`

But `PlayerRow` ends up being `[]` regardless of the value of `Player`.